# Can I redistribute a modified part of an open-source project under 3-clause BSD license

Tags: derivative-works, bsd

I would like to take a small stand-alone part of an open-source Python project (one class from a relatively big project), enhance it, and release it as separate project on PyPI so that I can use it independently. I will fully credit the project where the code is taken from originally. Below is the full license of the original project. <s>As far as I can tell it does not use one of a standard open-source licenses such as MIT.</s> As pointed out in comments, this is [3-Clause BSD license](https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause).

> Copyright (C) {years} {author name}
>   All rights reserved.
>
> Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
>   modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
>   are met:
>
> 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
>      notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
> 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
>      notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
>      the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
>      distribution.
> 3. The name of the author may not be used to endorse or promote
>      products derived from this software without specific prior
>      written permission.
>
> THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE AUTHOR ``AS IS'' AND ANY EXPRESS
>   OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
>   WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
>   ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR ANY
>   DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
>   DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE
>   GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
>   INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER
>   IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR
>   OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN
>   IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

My question is if Im legally allowed to do that. And if yes, under what license would I be able to release it under?

Comment: just saw https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165980/where-can-i-ask-about-software-licenses-licensing and wondering if this is correct site to ask this question. I see some similar licensing questions here so will leave here for now

Comment: The quoted license looks very MIT like. What's different?

Comment: The 3 restrictions seem different. hence Im not sure if Im allowed to fork and release part of it separately

Comment: "As far as I can tell it does not use one of a standard open-source licenses" – In what way is this different from the 3-clause BSD license?

Comment: its not! thanks @JörgWMittag. never seen it before. thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, it was clarified that original license is [3-Clause BSD license](https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause).

Open-source SE site contains answers related to that license and my question. https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4704/we-worked-with-bsd-license-software-and-modified-it-and-now-want-to-allow-others/4705#4705 and https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4546/bsd-3-clause-how-to-update-with-modifications.

It seems that changes could be distributed as long as original copyright notice is preserved.

Comment: Next time you are not sure about a license give a shot to my https://github.com/nexB/scancode-toolkit